# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh"

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to run postman collection in jenkins getting below error Could you please help on it . Thanks.

Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users.jenkins\workspace\Postman
[Postman] $ sh -xe C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\12\jenkins4131098184637934114.sh
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed

Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\Users.jenkins\workspace\Postman"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: You are running on windows. Windows by default doesnt have a shell. You either need to define the same in global jenkins or like install shell in windows on the jenkins user path.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135771/hudson-on-windows-error-java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-sh), you have two options:

1. On your `{jenkinsUrl}/job/{jobName}/configure`  build step you can choose "Execute Windows batch command" rather than "Execute shell"
2. In Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Shell, set the shell path
   as

   C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: Worked for me with optioned 2.

Answer (score 0):

I followed second method as mentioned by @Anderson-paiva. It worked. Thanks.

[image]